# Sandboxing in .net core

Tags: .net-core, sandbox

I was wondering how I can achieve sandboxing in .net core, since appdomains are not supported in .net core for this. Also, I can't use Virtualization or docket containers because these things are not available on my target machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per .NET Core docs, looks like your options are a bit limited.

> **Free of problematic tech.** .NET Core doesn’t include certain
>   technologies we decided to discontinue because we found them to be
>   problematic, for instance AppDomain and sandboxing. If the scenario
>   still makes sense for .NET Core, our plan is to have replacements. For
>   example, AssemblyLoadContext replaces AppDomains for loading and
>   isolating assemblies.
>
> ***App Domains***
>
> **Why was it discontinued?** AppDomains require runtime
>   support and are generally quite expensive. While still implemented by
>   CoreCLR, it’s not available in .NET Native and we don’t plan on adding
>   this capability there.
>
> **What should I use instead?** AppDomains were used for different
>   purposes. For code isolation, we recommend processes and/or
>   containers. For dynamic loading of assemblies, we recommend the new
>   AssemblyLoadContext class.

Since you cannot use containers, it looks like the only option is to run your sandbox in a separate process.

*Source*: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/02/10/porting-to-net-core/