# Are there any alternatives AppDomain?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Suppose I am making an extensible application.

The user can select a plug-in assembly and then a new interface element will appear.

However, how can I protect myself from incorrect assemblies?

For example, a plugin that starts an endless loop and the application stops responding.

Even if I add a CancellationToken to the signature, they can ignore it.

Before, I can undload a domain, but they aren’t in NetCore ...

Any alternatives?

Comment: You can have a look at [AssemblyLoadContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/understanding-assemblyloadcontext)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58468896/sandboxing-in-net-core

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski If a bad extension starts a thread, will it be safe terminated?